# Remove item from list<> inside string.join

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

```
String.Join("<br>", ProductList)
```

ProductList is a List.  So, this returns a tidy little:

Item1
   
Item2
   
Item3 etc

What I need to do is just remove the first item.

```
String.Join("<br>", ProductList.RemoveAt(0))
```

That doesn't work, because RemoveAt returns void.  I'm sure this is simple... I'll probably smack myself in the forehead when I see the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really simple using the [IEnumerable.Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) extension

```
String.Join("<br>", ProductList.Skip(1))
```

However this doesn't remove anything, just the first item in the list is skipped and not passed to the Join method

Comment: Perfect!  I did not know about .Skip.  Thanks!